# Shopify: Custom banner grid is not showing half of the pictures

Tags: shopify, liquid

I Have a custom product grid for one of the brands I am selling that has 4 tabs to hover and the content is changing in every tab. When i try to create another grid, 2 of the tabs are not showing the pictures i've inserted. First tab that's not showing pictures

[image: 1]

and 2 of the tabs are showing as needed.

Security section

[image: 2]

The code is the same for both sections.

```
 <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'Switches')" id="defaultOpen">Switches</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'Routers')">Routers</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'Security')">Security</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'Wireless')">Wireless</button>
      </div>
      <script type="lazyload2">
        // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
        setTimeout(function() { openCity(event, 'Switches'); document.getElementById('defaultOpen').className += " active"});
      </script>
      
        <div class="row tabcontent" id="Switches" style="margin-left:-10px;margin-right:-10px;">
        <div class="mobile-grid-2 col-md-{{ section.settings.banner_col_1 }} col-sm-{{ section.settings.banner_col_1 }}" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:15px;">
          {% if section.settings.image_banner_col_1 != blank  %}
          {% assign img_banner_col_1 = section.settings.image_banner_col_1 | img_url: "master" %}
          {% assign img_banner_col_1_alt = section.settings.image_banner_col_1_alt %}
          {% else %}
          {% assign img_banner_col_1 = 'img566x566.png' | asset_url %}
          {% endif %}
          <a href="{{ section.settings.banner_link_1 }}">
          <div class="banner-inner" style="background: radial-gradient(#Fff 10%, #e8e8e8);height: 598px;">
            <div class="grid-image">
              <img class="img-responsive lazyloaded lazy2 main" data-src="{{ img_banner_col_1 }}" alt="{{ img_banner_col_1_alt }}">
            </div>
            <div class="content-banner">
              {% if settings.language_enable %}
              <span class="lang1">{{ section.settings.content_banner_1 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
              <span class="lang2">{{ section.settings.content_banner_1 | split: '[lang2]' | last }}</span>
              {% else %}
              <span>{{ section.settings.content_banner_1 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-{{section.settings.banner_col_2}} col-sm-{{section.settings.banner_col_2}}" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:15px;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="mobile-grid banner_item col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
              {% if section.settings.image_banner_col_2_1 != blank  %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_2_1 = section.settings.image_banner_col_2_1 | img_url: "master" %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_2_1_alt = section.settings.image_banner_col_2_1_alt %}
              {% else %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_2_1 = 'img566x273.png' | asset_url %}
              {% endif %}
              <a href="{{ section.settings.banner_link_2_1 }}">
              <div class="banner-inner" style="background: radial-gradient(#Fff 10%, #e0e5e9);height: 294px;">
              <div class="grid-image">
                <img data-src="{{ img_banner_col_2_1}}" class="img-responsive lazyloaded lazy2 main" alt="{{ img_banner_col_2_1_alt }}">
              </div>
                <div class="content-banner"> 
                  {% if settings.language_enable %}
                  <span class="lang1">{{ section.settings.content_banner_2_1 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  <span class="lang2">{{ section.settings.content_banner_2_1 | split: '[lang2]' | last }}</span>
                  {% else %}
                  <span>{{ section.settings.content_banner_2_1 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="mobile-grid banner_item col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:10px;">
             {% if section.settings.image_banner_col_2_2 != blank  %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_2_2 = section.settings.image_banner_col_2_2 | img_url: "master" %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_2_2_alt = section.settings.image_banner_col_2_2_alt %}
              {% else %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_2_2 = 'img566x273.png' | asset_url %}
              {% endif %}
              <a href="{{ section.settings.banner_link_2_2 }}">
              <div class="banner-inner" style="background: radial-gradient(#Fff 10%, #eeecea); height: 294px;">
              <div class="grid-image">
                <img data-src="{{ img_banner_col_2_2}}" class="img-responsive lazyloaded lazy2 main" alt="{{ img_banner_col_2_2_alt }}">
              </div>
                <div class="content-banner"> 
                  {% if settings.language_enable %}
                  <span class="lang1">{{ section.settings.content_banner_2_2 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  <span class="lang2">{{ section.settings.content_banner_2_2 | split: '[lang2]' | last }}</span>
                  {% else %}
                  <span>{{ section.settings.content_banner_2_2 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mobile-grid banner_item col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-left:0px;">
              {% if section.settings.image_banner_col_3 != blank  %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_3 = section.settings.image_banner_col_3 | img_url: "master" %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_3_alt = section.settings.image_banner_col_3_alt %}
              {% else %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_3 = 'img566x273.png' | asset_url %}
              {% endif %}
              <a href="{{ section.settings.banner_link_3 }}">
              <div class="banner-inner" style="background: radial-gradient(#Fff 10%, #dbe2e4); height: 294px;">
                <div class="grid-image">
                <img data-src="{{ img_banner_col_3}}" class="img-responsive lazyloaded lazy2 main" alt="{{ img_banner_col_3_alt }}">
              </div>
                <div class="content-banner"> 
                  {% if settings.language_enable %}
                  <span class="lang1">{{ section.settings.content_banner_3 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  <span class="lang2">{{ section.settings.content_banner_3 | split: '[lang2]' | last }}</span>
                  {% else %}
                  <span>{{ section.settings.content_banner_3 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And this is the code i am using for other sections

```
      <div class="row tabcontent" id="Security" style="margin-left:-10px;margin-right:-10px;">
        <div class="mobile-grid-2 col-md-{{ section.settings.banner_col_7 }} col-sm-{{ section.settings.banner_col_7 }}" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:15px;">
          {% if section.settings.image_banner_col_7 != blank  %}
          {% assign img_banner_col_7 = section.settings.image_banner_col_7 | img_url: "master" %}
          {% assign img_banner_col_7_alt = section.settings.image_banner_col_7_alt %}
          {% else %}
          {% assign img_banner_col_7 = 'img566x566.png' | asset_url %}
          {% endif %}
          <a href="{{ section.settings.banner_link_7 }}">
          <div class="banner-inner" style="background: radial-gradient(#Fff 10%, #e8e8e8);height: 598px;">
            <div class="grid-image">
              <img class="img-responsive lazyloaded lazy2 main" data-src="{{ img_banner_col_7 }}" alt="{{ img_banner_col_7_alt }}">
            </div>
            <div class="content-banner">
              {% if settings.language_enable %}
              <span class="lang1">{{ section.settings.content_banner_7 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
              <span class="lang2">{{ section.settings.content_banner_7 | split: '[lang2]' | last }}</span>
              {% else %}
              <span>{{ section.settings.content_banner_7 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-{{section.settings.banner_col_8}} col-sm-{{section.settings.banner_col_8}}" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:15px;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="mobile-grid banner_item col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
              {% if section.settings.image_banner_col_8 != blank  %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_8 = section.settings.image_banner_col_8 | img_url: "master" %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_8_alt = section.settings.image_banner_col_8_alt %}
              {% else %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_8 = 'img566x273.png' | asset_url %}
              {% endif %}
              <a href="{{ section.settings.banner_link_8 }}">
              <div class="banner-inner" style="background: radial-gradient(#Fff 10%, #e0e5e9);height: 294px;">
              <div class="grid-image">
                <img data-src="{{ img_banner_col_8}}" class="img-responsive lazyloaded lazy2 main" alt="{{ img_banner_col_8_alt }}">
              </div>
                <div class="content-banner"> 
                  {% if settings.language_enable %}
                  <span class="lang1">{{ section.settings.content_banner_8 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  <span class="lang2">{{ section.settings.content_banner_8 | split: '[lang2]' | last }}</span>
                  {% else %}
                  <span>{{ section.settings.content_banner_8 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="mobile-grid banner_item col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:0px;">
              {% if section.settings.image_banner_col_9 != blank  %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_9 = section.settings.image_banner_col_9 | img_url: "master" %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_9_alt = section.settings.image_banner_col_9_alt %}
              {% else %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_9 = 'img566x273.png' | asset_url %}
              {% endif %}
              <a href="{{ section.settings.banner_link_9 }}">
              <div class="banner-inner" style="background: radial-gradient(#Fff 10%, #e0e5e9);height: 294px;">
              <div class="grid-image">
                <img data-src="{{ img_banner_col_9}}" class="img-responsive lazyloaded lazy2 main" alt="{{ img_banner_col_9_alt }}">
              </div>
                <div class="content-banner"> 
                  {% if settings.language_enable %}
                  <span class="lang1">{{ section.settings.content_banner_9 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  <span class="lang2">{{ section.settings.content_banner_9 | split: '[lang2]' | last }}</span>
                  {% else %}
                  <span>{{ section.settings.content_banner_9 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mobile-grid banner_item col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:10px;">
             {% if section.settings.image_banner_col_10 != blank  %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_10 = section.settings.image_banner_col_10 | img_url: "master" %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_10_alt = section.settings.image_banner_col_10_alt %}
              {% else %}
              {% assign img_banner_col_10 = 'img566x273.png' | asset_url %}
              {% endif %}
              <a href="{{ section.settings.banner_link_10 }}">
              <div class="banner-inner" style="background: radial-gradient(#Fff 10%, #eeecea); height: 294px;">
              <div class="grid-image">
                <img data-src="{{ img_banner_col_10}}" class="img-responsive lazyloaded lazy2 main" alt="{{ img_banner_col_10_alt }}">
              </div>
                <div class="content-banner"> 
                  {% if settings.language_enable %}
                  <span class="lang1">{{ section.settings.content_banner_10 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  <span class="lang2">{{ section.settings.content_banner_10 | split: '[lang2]' | last }}</span>
                  {% else %}
                  <span>{{ section.settings.content_banner_10 | split: '[lang2]' | first }}</span>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

What is the mistake i am making here?

I've tried copying the working grids code and edited from there. Still the same. Can't see banner parts.

Comment: from this description and code sample nothing is clear, if you able to share url, then someone able to help on it.

Comment: Since I am not taking it to live I don't think giving an url will help :(

Comment: No issues, have a great time